# Apostol, Spivak, or Khan Academy?

Tags: calculus, book-recommendation

This seems like a silly question, but time is a huge factor for me.

I will be taking a Calculus 2 class for my next semester, and having just finished up Calc 1 (ending on integrals), I want to supplement my studies outside of class so that I am prepared.

I have seen two authors, Apostol and Spivak, mentioned as the go-to for studying calculus.

During the semester I will not have an abundant amount of time to do this sort of on-the-side studying, so I am wondering what the best option would be to make sure I can handle Calculus 2:

Apostol, Spivak, Khan Academy, or something completely different?

Topics covered in my calc 2 course:
Techniques of integration, arc length, solids of revolution, applications, polar coordinates, parametric equations, infinite sequences and series, power series.

(Computer science major, interested in all things math)

Comment: I can personally recommend Spivak. Sure KhanAcademy is great, but it won't really help you to be able to do proofs.

Comment: Spivak or Apostol. My vote would be for Spivak. I never learn much by seeing a lecture, unless the lecture is great. These two books give you a broad idea, and are incredibly motivating.

Comment: Apostol, Spivak and Khan Academy are in **completely** different leagues...

Comment: It depends on what Calc 2 looks like at your school. If it's lots of computation and formulas, but no proofs...then Spivak and Apostol aren't the right prep. (Spivak is, however, a great foundation for later studies in mathematics, which may not be what you school's courses -- or you! -- are aiming at.)

Comment: That list of topics is fine...but not detailed enough. Perhaps a question about Calc 1 would help: Did you actually study a proof of Rolle's theorem, or of the Intermediate Value Theorem? Do you know what the least upper bound of a set of real numbers is? If not, Spivak's book is not well-matched to your course, and nor is Apostol's.

Comment: I vote Apostol since Spivak shows off too much and skipped lots of good details that you ended up learn nothing.

Comment: Thank you, everyone. And John, the course only mentioned 2 proofs, but even then my professor made sure to say that we shouldn't be concerned with proofs. So I think everyone is right. I am very interested in the two books, but for now I'll stick to some online lectures to actually gain a working understanding of what I need.

Answer (score 7):

First you should really try to use the recommended textbook and follow your professor's lectures. That being said, it never hurts to have a backup plan but we really need to know more information before suggesting alternatives.  Is this course the standard undergrad Calc. II, or Calculus for math majors?  Sure Spivak and Apostol come highly recommended... *by mathematicians*.  But honestly if you are just trying to get a prereq. out of the way, I would go another route such as the standard text by Stewart.  Khan Academy may help but most of my students who use Khan are lost causes.  That is, they don't come to class or do the homework exercises, then they try Khan at the last minute to avoid failing.  Your professor should be your best resource.

Comment: Thank you very much. I completely agree with your suggestion .